# showing notification in x days

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time 
import pickle
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk

def done_():
    item = e1.get()
    name = e2.get()
    time = e3.get()

    now = datetime.now()
    end = now + timedelta(days=e6)

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        dc = pickle.load(f)

    dc[time] = [name, item]

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(dc, f)

    e1.set("")
    e2.set("")
    e3.set("")
    check_time()


def notify_info(n, m, o)
    root.bell()
    messagebox.showinfo("Name:-{}", "Item:-{}\t, time:-{}".format(n, m, o))


def check_time():
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        sa = pickle.load(f)

    now = datetime.now() 
    for s, j in sa.items():
        if str(now) == s: #if time == now()
            time = str(s)
            name = sa[now][0]
            item = sa[now][1]
            return notify_info(name, item, time)

#how do i continusly check if the now() == time in dic until its true
        else:
            pass
        root.after(100, check_time)
#root.after just popped so many  windows

filename = "fuckup.pk"
def main_():

    root = Tk()
    root.title("V0.1")
    e1 = StringVar()
    e2 = StringVar()
    e3 = IntVar()
    check_time()

    lbl = Label(root).pack()
    en = Entry(root,textvariable=e1)
    en.pack()

    en1 = Entry(root, textvariable=e2)
    en1.pack()

    en2 = Entry(root, textvariable=e3)
    en2.pack()

    btn = Button(root,text="click",command=done_)
    btn.pack()
    root.after(10, check_time)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_()
```

I am trying to make a program which will take a input of Name, item , and time.I want the program save the details to the pickle file and check if now is the time and show the notification of the name and item.But i couldn't figure out how do i check if the time has come.I am having difficulty checking the every seconds if the now() is time.

Comment: What does the file look like? 
You probably want to update your code to use more reasonable var names. It is very hard to read ATM. If you want to check every second, just do `root.after(1000, check_time)`.

Comment: if i did root.after(1000, check_time) many windows poped up

Comment: the file contains a dic as dic ={"name":["item",time]} where the time is the one i want to check for

Comment: Anyways, your code has a lot of issues and bugs, it does not run.
You can't call `StringVar()` & `IntVar()` before the `Tk()`.
Root is not global var, so you can't use it in your `check_time` func. Perhaps you can pass it in as argument.

Again, the variable names are not meaningful. Hard for us to understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: sorry for that ...I want a code to check if the datetime.now() is equal to the entry provided and if its equal it show show the notificatication that the time has ended

Comment: here e1 is item name ,e2 is item and important e3 is the time which will be compared to the datetime.now() .I just want a way to continusly check if the time is now until its true

Comment: `e3` seems like to be an integer that represents the delta of days comparing to current day, which is not intuitive for the purpose of your program. You may want to decide what is the time format you want first, such as how detail it should be. Does it have days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.? Then figure out what you expect the user to enter for the time value.

Comment: i want the user to input the day and compare it with now() where the hrs, mins and seconds will be same but only the days is different.

Comment: how do u suggest me to compare the time with and how can i continusly check if the the time has come to show the notification.Thank you for ur time and help

Comment: some code example would be appriciated

Comment: all i want is a way to check if the time has ended and if it has ended then show the notification.. can you plz provide me example code for it

Comment: someone help plz